# How to draw a quarter circle in objective-C

Tags: iphone, objective-c

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Circle to Circle Segment Collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226356/circle-to-circle-segment-collision)

I am the beginner with iOS development. Do you know how to draw a image like this http://www.hoodshomecenters.com/product_images/v/723/QuarterRound__65714_zoom.jpg with CoreGraphic?

Comment: You should first look if there are answers on Stackoverflow. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226356/circle-to-circle-segment-collision

Answer (score 12):

This is the code for drawing the arc portion. Once it is drawn then you can draw lines within it.

```
#include <math.h>

CGFloat radius = 100;

CGFloat starttime = M_PI/6; //1 pm = 1/6 rad
CGFloat endtime = M_PI;  //6 pm = 1 rad

//draw arc
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(radius,radius);
UIBezierPath *arc = [UIBezierPath bezierPath]; //empty path
[arc moveToPoint:center];
CGPoint next;
next.x = center.x + radius * cos(starttime);
next.y = center.y + radius * sin(starttime);
[arc addLineToPoint:next]; //go one end of arc
[arc addArcWithCenter:center radius:radius startAngle:starttime endAngle:endtime clockwise:YES]; //add the arc
[arc addLineToPoint:center]; //back to center

[[UIColor yellowColor] set];
[arc fill];
```

You need to overwrite the drawRect method of the view in which you will be used for showing this drawing.

Comment: Thank you all for helping me!

Comment: @QuangPham If the answer helps you then please upvote and tick.

Answer (score 2):

You can draw an arc segment with the `UIBezierPath` class using the method `bezierPathWithArcCenter:radius:startAngle:endAngle:clockwise`. Have a look [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/BezierPaths/BezierPaths.html)

You will also need to create a path for your lines using the combination of `CGContextMoveToPoint/ CGContextAddLineToPoint`

Last you stroke your lines by invoking the `stroke` method on your path.

**EDIT**
To draw the inner lines you probably want to clip those: this is done with the `CGContextClip` function

Answer (score 0):

You can certainly use

```
void CGContextAddArcToPoint
```

The documentation:

[CGContext reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/graphicsimaging/reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html)